# Uninstall Crystal Report 13.0.17.2096 for Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am trying uninstall Crystal Report for VS version 13.0.17.2096. 
However I am getting the following error message:

[image]

Use source:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\RarSFX0\package\
```

And when I click ok a new message appears:

[image]

What do I do to uninstall the CR?

Note, I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio versions 2017, 2015, and 2013 installed on this machine.

Comment: You need to locate the installation executable for the version of Crystal Reports you installed in order to uninstall it.

Comment: And if you can't find it (because you deleted the installer) then download it again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as you said and it worked. I had to download the installer, but now everything is fine